# Is there other way have to active dark mode to whole app in react-native without following method?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mobile-application, darkmode

<SafeAreaView style                 = {[styles.container,isDarkMode && darkStyles.container]}>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        : 1,
backgroundColor                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             : '#fff',
paddingHorizontal                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           : 20,
paddingTop                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  : 0,
},
scrollViewContainer: {
flexGrow                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    : 0.25,
},
inputContainer: {
marginBottom                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                : 20,
},
label: {
fontSize                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    : 18,
fontWeight                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  : 'bold',
marginBottom                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                : 10,
color                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       : 'darkblue',
},
input: {
borderWidth                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 : 1,
borderColor                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 : 'darkblue',
borderRadius                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                : 10,
fontSize                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    : 16,
padding                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     : 10,
alignContent                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                : 'center',
},
dropdown: {
borderWidth                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 : 2,
borderColor                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 : 'darkblue',
borderRadius                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                : 10,
fontSize                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    : 16,
padding                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     : 10,
height                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      : 50,
backgroundColor                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             : '#bef',

},
pickerItem: {
color                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       : 'darkblue',
backgroundColor                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             : '#bef', // Change the color of the drop-down menu items here
},
submitButton: {
backgroundColor                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             : 'darkblue',
borderRadius                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                : 10,
paddingVertical                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             : 10,
paddingHorizontal                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           : 20,
alignItems                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  : 'center',
marginBottom                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                : 2,
},
submitButtonText: {
fontFamily                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  : 'Poppins-Bold',
color                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       : '#fff',
fontSize                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    : 18,
},
Home_icon: {
marginRight                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 : 2,
},
formContainer: {
flex                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        : 1,
justifyContent                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              : 'center',
},
ViewButtonText: {

```
color                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       : 'darkblue',
fontSize                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    : 18,
textDecorationLine                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          : 'underline',
```

},
ViewButtonContainer: {
flexDirection                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               : 'row',
justifyContent                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              : 'flex-start',
alignItems                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  : 'flex-start',
marginTop                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   : 5,
}

});

const darkStyles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
backgroundColor                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             : '#333333',
opacity                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     : 0.6,

},
label: {
fontSize                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    : 18,
fontWeight                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  : 'bold',
marginBottom                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                : 10,
color                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       : 'white',
},

dropdown: {
borderWidth                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 : 2,
borderColor                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 : 'darkblue',
borderRadius                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                : 10,
fontSize                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    : 16,
padding                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     : 10,
height                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      : 50,
backgroundColor                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             : 'grey', // Change the background color of the Picker component in dark mode here
},
pickerItem: {
color                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       : 'white', // Change the color of the drop-down menu items in dark mode here
},
});

Other method can use to react-native app get to dark mode.

Comment: No , there isn't if you are using toggler to switch dark mode in react then you have to manage it with state. hmmm you can use tailwindcss dark mode feaeture too if you don't want to use this method. tailwind's dark mode is pretty easy and it works only if default system's theme is set to dark mode. you can add toggler too.

Comment: this is react-native mobile app